# Change task-specific history setting for Windows schtasks

Tags: windows, schtasks

There appears to be a way to enable and disable the task history of specific tasks, even if they are in the same hierachy or folder (in this case in the folder \ of all tasks).

Case in point:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- Scheduled task "\task_one" with entries in history
- Scheduled task "\task_two" without entries in history
- Both tasks were executed in the last 30 days and should have a history.

The scheduled tasks are both active (last execution in the past few days with different results), but the history appears to be disabled for task_two.

How can I manually configure this? Can I possibly do this by using CIM/WIM APIs?
Yes, this appears to be an unsupported approach, but there seems to be a way and I'd like to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was wrong.

Log rotation deletes log entries, that's why task_two (that only executes once a month) didn't have log entries, unlike task_one (which executes daily).

I'm leaving this behind as a reminder for myself and others.